# How to create jquery array with key values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, key-value

Is there a way we can create an array in JQuery with key and values?
I want to loop through the `TFNDailySummaryReportData` array and assign its DateWiseSalesData's Name property to key and DateWiseSalesData as value.

```
for (var i = 0; i < TFNDailySummaryReportData.length; i++) 
{
    var keyValueArray = {
         Key: TFNDailySummaryReportData[i].DateWiseSalesData.Name;
         value: TFNDailySummaryReportData[i].DateWiseSalesData
     }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this? If yes, how?

Comment: keyValuesArray.push("TFNDailySummaryReportData[i].DateWiseSalesData.Name" : "TFNDailySummaryReportData[i].DateWiseSalesData")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close, You can define an array and use [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method to populate it.

```
var arr=[];
for (var i = 0; i < TFNDailySummaryReportData.length; i++) 
{
    arr.push({
         Key: TFNDailySummaryReportData[i].DateWiseSalesData.Name;
         value: TFNDailySummaryReportData[i].DateWiseSalesData
     })
}
```

You can also use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var arr=TFNDailySummaryReportData.map(function(value){
    return {
         Key: value.DateWiseSalesData.Name;
         value: value.DateWiseSalesData
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with jQuery. Arrays are basic JavaScript, and you can map the KVP based objects to a new array as such:

Using ES6:

```
const keyValueArray = TFNDailySummaryReportData.map(x => { 
    return { [x.DateWiseSalesData.Name]: x.DateWiseSalesData };
});
```

Using ES5:

```
var keyValueArray = TFNDailySummaryReportData.map(function(x) {
    return { x.DateWiseSalesData.Name : x.DateWiseSalesData };
});
```